# Matplotlib figure subplots do not look alike

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Hey I would like to have the second plot (significant/unsignificant)to look like the first one but I don't know how I get it to that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a binary mask of significant change
change_sign = np.where(abs(m3c2_distances) > uncertainties['lodetection'], True, False)

# Create the figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 6), subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax2, ax3 = axs

# Plot the level of detection values
l = ax2.scatter(corepoints[:, 0], corepoints[:, 1], corepoints[:, 2], c=uncertainties['lodetection'], cmap='viridis', vmax=2.8, s=1)
plt.colorbar(l, format='%.1f', label='Level of detection [m]', ax=ax2, extend='max', shrink=0.5, pad=0.15)
ax2.set_title('Level of Detection')

# Plot the significant change values (boolean)
# Plot the significant change values (boolean)
sc1 = ax3.scatter(corepoints[~change_sign][:, 0], corepoints[~change_sign][:, 1], corepoints[~change_sign][:, 2], c='blue', s=1, label='Not significant change')
sc2 = ax3.scatter(corepoints[change_sign][:, 0], corepoints[change_sign][:, 1], corepoints[change_sign][:, 2], c='red', s=1, label='Significant change')
ax3.legend(handles=[sc1, sc2])

ax3.set_title('Significant change')

# Add plot elements
for ax in axs:
    ax.set_xlabel('Easting [m]', labelpad=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Northing [m]', labelpad=15)
    ax.set_zlabel('Depth [m]', labelpad=15)
    ax.set_aspect('auto')  # Adjust to 'auto' for a more 3D-like appearance
    ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=110.)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

#plt.savefig('m3c2plots_2012_2022.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

At the moment it looks like this, but I would like to have the same "extent" and "3D" for the second plot.
[image]

Comment: You adjust the x, y, and z-limits of your second axis to mirror the first by: `ax3.set_xlim3d(ax2.get_xlim3d()); ax3.set_ylim3d(ax2.get_ylim3d()); ax3.set_zlim3d(ax2.get_zlim3d());`